# Laravel @include view with variable from function

Tags: laravel, variables, view, include, laravel-blade

I got i variable $b from function

```
 public function hello()
{
    $b = "bla bla bla ";
    return view('hello',compact('b'));

}
```

[image]

if i open the view i can see the variable

```
hello
```

{{$b}}

[image]

But if I use it in home view as @include('hello') then the undefined variable

[image]

[image]

```
@include('hello')
```

Comment: is `hello` your blade name?

Comment: Yes hello is blades name

Answer (score 0):

You must pass variable  again in function that call home

So , in function that call from route home u mast pass $b like that

```
function home(){
   // some code 

    $b = "bla bla bla ";

    return view('home',compact('b'));
}
```

Comment: This is one of solutions, but i wanna hello blade include in multiple other blades to, so i will need to pass the variable again in each blade. The idea is that hello will have a lot of variables from batabase depending of users sessions

Comment: so u need to share variable to all view